# How i fix this syntax error for a tweepy script?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, bigdata

Hello i'm trying to learn programing for a project.

i've been working on a simple script (using tweepy) to download tweets from a search of a keyword into a .csv format. However i keep getting a sintax error in multiple lines (from 28 to 38) and i don't know what is wrong at this point, can somebody tell me what's wrong?

here is the code i've been working on...

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#import modules
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import unicodecsv
from unidecode import unidecode
import csv

from textblob import TextBlob

ckey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
csecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
atoken = "XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
asecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret, 'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)
fName= raw_input("Nombre del Archivo: ")+'.csv'

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=('dulceveneno'), since='2014-09-16', until='2017-07-25').items(5):

    tweet_info = [tweet.author.name.encode('utf8')
                tweet.author.screen_name.encode('utf8')
                tweet.created_at
                tweet.text.encode('utf8')
                tweet.retweeted
                tweet.favorited
                tweet.user.location.encode('utf8')
                tweet.user.time_zone
                tweet.geo
                tweet.entities.get('hashtags')]

    with open(fName, 'wb') as file:
        writer = unicodecsv.writer(file, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
       # Write header row.
        writer.writerow(["Nombre",
                         "UserName",
                         "Fecha",
                         "Tweet",
                         "Retweet?"
                         "Favs"
                         "Ubicación",
                         "Horario",
                         "Geo",
                         "Hashtags"])


            # Write data to CSV.
            writer.writerow(tweet_info)


        # Show progress.
        print("DONE!" % q)
```

the problem is in the "tweet_info" part i guess...

Comment: Can you please post the log/ error message ?

Comment: it just highlight that part and says that there's an syntax error in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the actual error yet, but I can see for `tweet_info` you do not have any commas `,` for the elements in the list.

It should be:

```
tweet_info = [tweet.author.name.encode('utf8'),
            tweet.author.screen_name.encode('utf8'),
            tweet.created_at,
            tweet.text.encode('utf8'),
            tweet.retweeted,
            tweet.favorited,
            tweet.user.location.encode('utf8'),
            tweet.user.time_zone,
            tweet.geo,
            tweet.entities.get('hashtags')]
```